# QPushButton bug under QT5 while pushing to go to fullscreen on macos

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I made a small video app with fullscreen support. While the video is playing I can push a button in my video controller and the app changes to fullscreen.
The strength thing is, when I'm in fullscreen the button has still somehow the focus in this way that when I move over it , it thinks I pushed (also the hover of the button is active even when I'm not over it with the mouse)
This behaviour end then up in a endless with to and from fullscreen when I'm not moving the mouse after pushing the button

I had here a similar problem in Qt4, but here the mouse over was only active after pushing

so perhaps somebody has an idea what's happening here, could not find anything in the Qt buglists

Georg

Comment: Please show us the relevant code and perhaps a short film showing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a bug or an intended behaviour, nevertheless you may try to solve this problem in several ways. In the slot called whenever you change the size of the window, call one or several of the following `QPushButton` methods:

1. `clearFocus()` - that should make the button stop receiving keyboard/mouse input;
2. `releaseKeyboard()` and `releaseMouse()` should effectively do the same;

If you don't need the button while in fullscreen, you can also simply make it stop receiving any user input at all:

3. disable it (`setEnabled(false)`);
4. make it invisible (invisible widgets don't receive keyboard/mouse input)  by calling `setVisible(false)`;
5. `disconnect()` the button and thus make it stop receiving any signals, and `connect()` it again after turning the fullscreen mode off.